# Call a function from a string name in (Emacs) Lisp

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

Given a string, built by various concatenation, "my-func-name", I would like to call the associated function.

As `funcall` expects a function object as parameter, I would like to know if there is a way to retrieve the function reference by its name, so I can execute it.

Hint: I am currently using the Emacs Lisp dialect.

Thank you very much

Bonus: Sample dummy code

```
(defun my-func-name ()
  "My function."
  (message "Hello"))

(setq mfname "my-func-name")

;; Not working, obviously
;; (funcall mfname)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Get the symbol of that name with `intern`, and then `funcall` it:

```
(funcall (intern "my-func-name"))
```

Comment: and if (setq fname = "myfunc") how to call fname?

Comment: @RichieHH That would be `(funcall (intern fname))`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Silly me.  I  put the Q wrong.  But I'm sorted now I actually needed (funcall (symbol-val (intern-soft  myVarHoldingFunctionNameAsString))). Though looking at that I need to go play in *scratch* again. One day the whole string/symbol thing will click...